# Phonegap: can't make localStorage persist

Tags: cordova, persistence, local-storage, persist, lawnchair

So I init everything:

```
var Store = new Lawnchair({table:'mightapp', adaptor:'gears'}, 
    function(s) {
    var obj = {msg: 'hooray!'};

    s.save({key: "msg", value: obj});
});
```

Then I comment out the message to test if it persisted...

```
var Store = new Lawnchair({table:'mightapp', adaptor:'gears'}, 
    function(s) {
    //var obj = {msg: 'hooray!'};

    //s.save({key: "msg", value: obj});
});
```

And it doesn't -- what am I doing wrong?  I'm making a fitness app and I need to persist people's workouts/workout stats pretty much permanently... should I just do some file i/o?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dom` adapter works fine for me. Here is the code I am using to persist data across application restart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var store = new Lawnchair({
        adapter: "dom",
        name: "testing"
    }, function(store) {
    });

    store.exists('dhaval', function(available){
        var preStr = "";

        // check whether required data is available, if not create it
        if(available){
            preStr = "data is already available, ";
        }else{
            preStr = "data is not available, ";
            var me = {
                key: 'dhaval'
            };

            // save it
            store.save(me);
        }

        // access it later... even after app restart!
        store.get('dhaval', function(me) {
            $("#data").html(preStr + JSON.stringify(me));
        });
    });
</script>
```

For full source check git repo [android-cordova-lawnchair](https://github.com/dhavaln/cordova-examples/tree/master/android-cordova-lawnchair)

Comment: I did this and it's all working out fine now, it seems like... can't  thank you enough!
`   Store = new Lawnchair({adapter: "dom", name:'mightapp'}, 
    function() {
     this.save({key: "msg", value: {msg: 'hooray!'}});
    });`

Comment: Hi @dhaval I'm glad to see this solution. However it didn't work for me. After the app is eliminated from the RAM on my android device, everything including localStorage is gone. So is there a way to prevent this? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't appear DOM/Local Storage is actually used as a default so don't forget to specify it like the example above!

Answer (score 1):

Try switching your adaptor to "dom" as I don't think "gears" is supported anymore in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I was using DOM (the default) before I tried gears :(

BUT, I will try again regardless